# How can I get the value of ng-repeat when clicking on it

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Can anybody help me in getting the ng-repeat value while we click on it.

```
<ul ng-repeat="section in sections">
<li>
  <a href='#'>{{section.name}}</a>
</li>
<ul>
```

Comment: A directive would give easy, clean access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this example I've made: http://jsbin.com/UWodob/1/ using ng-click you can get the value of the item being clicked.